How to recover files changed by malware
My server files and backup files have been infected by RedRose malware.
Is there anyone to have the same experience related to this issue?
Having a decrypt file or method will rescue me from this obstacle situation.
No security products are used on the server.
This name have been pasted to the files:
1419.bak.blsdks-adbf-8888-a182-115a6858a90a.RedRose

@vidarlo thanks to notice my question, but it totally far from your mention question. I want to find a decrypt way of RedRose infected files. I can remove or prevent malware at the moment, but I want to recover data.

In general we don't do such questions, which is why we have a canonical Q&A on it. The answer you'll get here is nuke it from orbit & restore from backup.

@vidarlo I am aware that you intend to clear me, but I think maybe someone had the same experience and can decrypt it. Restoring is one way, but at the moment, it is impossible.

I would suggest that what you /want/ and what you /need/ are different things.
If it was /easy/ to break RedRose's encryption then hackers would no longer use it for these attacks.  You /might/ break it, after a LOT of trying, but the easier (and far safer) option, as has already been mentioned, is to "burn" the machine, spin up a new one and restore clean files from your backups.
As you've also learned, your backups should be held on a different server.

@PhillW. Yes, I want to decrypt the file and as you mentioned it is impossible. Alright, I am not IT administrator of them, they had big mistaken to store data on the same vm, will I prepare another vm to transfer it. Overall, try to burn it!!
